# PHP array: count or sizeof?

Tags: php

To find the number of elements in a PHP `$array`, which is faster/better/stronger?

`count($array)` or `sizeof($array)` ?

### Edit

Thanks to Andy Lester, I have refined my question to mean from a multilingual perspective.  The manual commenters say

> "[sizeof] does not mean the same in
>   many other languages based on C"

Is this true?

Comment: Very nice question. But here is a good benchmark site, that says sizeof is just a 21µs faster

Answer (score 233, accepted):

I would use `count()` if they are the same, as in my experience it is more common, and therefore will cause less developers reading your code to say "`sizeof()`, what is that?" and having to consult the documentation.

I think it means `sizeof()` does not work like it does in C (calculating the size of a datatype). It probably made this mention explicitly because PHP is written in C, and provides a lot of identically named wrappers for C functions (`strlen()`, `printf()`, etc)

Comment: `what is that?" and having to consult the documentation.` that's what brought me here lol

Answer (score 115):

According to [phpbench](http://phpbench.com/):

Is it worth the effort to calculate the length of the loop in advance?

```
//pre-calculate the size of array
$size = count($x); //or $size = sizeOf($x);

for ($i=0; $i<$size; $i++) {
    //...
}

//don't pre-calculate
for ($i=0; $i<count($x); $i++) { //or $i<sizeOf($x);
    //...
}
```

A loop with 1000 keys with 1 byte values are given.

```
                  +---------+----------+
                  | count() | sizeof() |
+-----------------+---------+----------+
| With precalc    |     152 |      212 |
| Without precalc |   70401 |    50644 |
+-----------------+---------+----------+  (time in µs)
```

So I personally prefer to use *count()* instead of *sizeof()* *with pre calc*.

Comment: Please tell only which takes less time. Else the answer is quite complicated and confusing too! Thanks

Comment: what version of php were you testing with? Newer versions have a lot of optimisations which may make these results quite different

Comment: why is sizeof faster without saving it's result into a variable but otherwise it's the other way around? is this some bad design choice in the php interpreter that causes some sort of selective overhead? i would like to know how you benchmarked this, the microsecond measurement worries me. maybe try running this a huge amount of times in an outer for loop?

Comment: what do you mean with "pre calc"?

Comment: @rubo77 See the above code; "pre-calc" is determining the size of the array once, before the for-loop. Without "pre-calc" is determining the size of the array inside the for-loop

Comment: This answer shows the benefit of caching the count in a variable before a loop. I fail to see how this is relevant to the question.

Comment: Unrelated to OP's question, but what a strange implementation. You'd think these would be identical, but instead the refactor apparently introduces a large performance decrease at best and might introduce bugs if you change $x in the loop.

Answer (score 43):

They are identical according to [`sizeof()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sizeof.php)

In the absence of any reason to worry about "faster", always optimize for the human.  Which makes more sense to the human reader?

Comment: not always. sometimes you have many millions of data points to work. so even micro adds up. so performance dictates choice.

Comment: @TadasV. They already covered that in the answer by stating "In the absence of any reason to worry about faster"

Comment: sorry for some reason missed the clearly stated exception:)

Answer (score 24):

According to the website, `sizeof()` is an alias of `count()`, so they should be running the same code. Perhaps `sizeof()` has a little bit of overhead because it needs to resolve it to `count()`? It should be very minimal though.

Comment: Well, sorry for guessing? I was just stating that they're actually the same thing. Then, I made a logical inference that using an alias for a function instead of the actual function might be very minimally slower, but admited that i really have no idea by prefacing it with the word "perhaps." Sorry if that offended you. Maybe next time i'll use the word "infinitesimal."

Answer (score 15):

I know this is old but just wanted to mention that [I tried this](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.sizeof.php#123025) with PHP 7.2:

```
<?php
//Creating array with 1 000 000 elements
$a = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; ++$i)
{
    $a[] = 100;
}

//Measure
$time = time();
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000000; ++$i)
{
    $b = count($a);
}
print("1 000 000 000 iteration of count() took ".(time()-$time)." sec\n");

$time = time();
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000000; ++$i)
{
    $b = sizeof($a);
}
print("1 000 000 000 iteration of sizeof() took ".(time()-$time)." sec\n");
?>
```

and the result was:

```
1 000 000 000 iteration of count() took 414 sec
1 000 000 000 iteration of sizeof() took 1369 sec
```

So just use `count()`.

UPDATE:

On PHP 8.3 the speed is identical:

```
1 000 000 000 iteration of count() took 10 sec
1 000 000 000 iteration of sizeof() took 10 sec
```

Comment: This is interesting. What PHP version do you use?

Comment: @waza I'm using PHP 7.2

Comment: With PHP 7.3.3 :   
`1 000 000 000 iteration of count() took 525 sec`  
`1 000 000 000 iteration of sizeof() took 1361 sec`

Comment: with PHP 7.0 and ubuntu machine
`1 000 000 000 iteration of count() took 38 sec
1 000 000 000 iteration of sizeof() took 46 sec`

Answer (score 8):

`sizeof()` is just an alias of `count()`
as mentioned here

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sizeof.php

Comment: +alex  yes it does. I see two links. Did you expect him to rewrite sizeof ? LOL :p

Answer (score 0):

Both are used to count elements in a array. sizeof() function is an alias of count() function used in PHP. However, count() function is faster and better than sizeof().

Answer (score -4):

Please use count function, Here is a example how to count array in a element

```
$cars = array("Volvo","BMW","Toyota");
echo count($cars);
```

The `count()` function returns the number of elements in an array.

The `sizeof()` function returns the number of elements in an array.

The `sizeof()` function is an alias of the `count()` function.

Comment: "Please use count function" - why?