# Which is a better way to check if an array has more than one element?

Tags: php, arrays

I just need to check if an array has more than one element. 
I am trying to do it this way :

```
if (isset($arr['1']))
```

the other traditional way is

```
if (sizeof($arr)>1)
```

Which of the two is better? In such situaions, how should I judge between two alternate methods?
Is there any performance check meter available to measure which is better?

Comment: Assumption here is $arr is validated for an array already! That means, before it comes to this if condition check, its already checked if its an array.

Comment: http://phparraylength.com/

Answer (score 348, accepted):

Use this

```
if (sizeof($arr) > 1) {
     ....
}
```

Or

```
if (count($arr) > 1) {
     ....
}
```

`sizeof()` is an alias for `count()`, they work the same.

**Edit:**
Answering the second part of the question:
The two lines of code in the question are not alternative methods, they perform different functions. The first checks if the value at `$arr['1']` is set, while the second returns the number of elements in the array.

Comment: @N.B.: The question was edited, the initial code was `if (sizeof($arr))`, which translated to `if (sizeof($arr) == 1)` - clearly that doesn't check if the array has **more than one** element. This answer is correct, and I see no reason to down-vote, hence my upvote.

Comment: I'll admit that I didn't take a look at the original version of the question, which this answer is a reply to. The context is different, and I apologize for labelling the answer as wrong. It's not wrong, if you look at the original question. It's bad for the edited question.

Comment: The second code snippet in the question will check if the value at $arr['1'] is set or not, it is not concerned about the count. This was not addressed in the answer, just thought I'd mention this and hope the author of the answer will update the answer :).

Comment: @AndersM. thanks for pointing that out. I've reflected it in the answer.

Comment: I don something like :
<pre> <code>for index in 0..<3
        {
            guard let testTop:Prediciton = topPredictions[index] else
            {
                //your default object
                
            }
            predictionResult.append(testTop)
        }
</code></pre> 
in swift 4

Answer (score 46):

`if(is_array($arr) && count($arr) > 1)`

Just to be sure that $arr is indeed an array.

`sizeof` is an alias of `count`, I prefer to use count because:

1. 1 less character to type
2. sizeof at a quick glance might mean a size of an array in terms of memory, too technical :(

Comment: @AlixAxel hmm, but if $arr is a string, count($arr) would return character count of that string so ya

Comment: No, if `$arr` is a string, it'll return `1`.

Comment: From the manual: *Returns the number of elements in var. **If var is not an array or an object with implemented Countable interface, 1 will be returned. There is one exception, if var is NULL, 0 will be returned***.

Comment: @AlixAxel oh ok... wow thanks, didn't know that :o... In any case I'm just gonna leave it there in case OP wants to differentiate between a String and Array (regardless of size) Thanks for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 6):

```
if (count($arr) >= 2)
{
  // array has at least 2 elements
}
```

`sizeof()` is an alias for `count()`. Both work with non-arrays too, but *they will only return values greater than 1 if the argument is either an array or a `Countable` object*, so you're pretty safe with this.

Answer (score 6):

Obviously using `count($arr) > 1` (`sizeof` is just an alias for `count`) is the best solution.
Depending on the structure of your array, there might be tons of elements but no `$array['1']` element.

Answer (score 6):

Use `count()`

```
if (count($my_array) > 1) {
// do
}
```

this page explains it pretty well http://phparraylength.com/

Answer (score 6):

I prefer the `count()` function instead of `sizeOf()` as `sizeOf()` is only an alias of `count()` and does not mean the same in many other languages. Many programmers expect `sizeof()` to return the amount of memory allocated.

Comment: Also explained here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974385/php-array-count-or-sizeof 

This is valuable since this question is now a top Google hit for `sizeof` vs `count`

Answer (score 4):

For checking an array empty() is better than sizeof().

If the array contains huge amount of data. It will takes more times for counting the size of the array. But checking empty is always easy.

```
//for empty
  if(!empty($array))
     echo 'Data exist';
  else 
     echo 'No data';


 //for sizeof
 if(sizeof($array)>1)
      echo 'Data exist';
 else 
    echo 'No data';
```

Answer (score 3):

isset() only checks if a variable is set.. Has got nothing to do with size or what the array contains

Answer (score 2):

I assume $arr is an array then this is what you are looking for

```
if ( sizeof($arr) > 1) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The first method
`if (isset($arr['1']))`
will not work on an associative array.

For example, the following code displays "Nope, not more than one."

```
$arr = array(
    'a' => 'apple',
    'b' => 'banana',
);

if (isset($arr['1'])) {
    echo "Yup, more than one.";
} else {
    echo "Nope, not more than one.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do my array looping and getting filled defaults accordingly in Swift 4/5

```
   for index in 0..<3
    {
        let isIndexValid = allObjects.indices.contains(index)
        var yourObject:Class = Class()
        if isIndexValid { yourObject = allObjects[index]}
        resultArray.append(yourObject)
    }
```