# PHP and Concrete 5 count subpages

Tags: php, concrete5

Making mobile site with Concrete5 and using page list block with custom template. I'm trying to count sub pages using PHP.

```
<?php  foreach ($pages as $page):

// Prepare data for each page being listed...
$title = $th->entities($page->getCollectionName());
$url = $nh->getLinkToCollection($page);
$target = ($page->getCollectionPointerExternalLink() != '' && $page->openCollectionPointerExternalLinkInNewWindow()) ? '_blank' : $page->getAttribute('nav_target');
$target = empty($target) ? '_self' : $target;
$description = $page->getCollectionDescription();
$description = $controller->truncateSummaries ? $th->shorten($description, $controller->truncateChars) : $description;
$description = $th->entities($description);
$mies = 0;
?>
<li class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li ui-btn-up-c" data-theme="c"><div aria-hidden="true" class="ui-btn-inner ui-li"><div class="ui-btn-text"><a target="<?php  echo $target ?>" class="ui-link-inherit" href="<?php  echo $url ?>">
<h2 class="ui-li-heading"><?php  echo $title ?></h2>
<p class="ui-li-desc"><?php  echo $description ?></p>
</a>
</div><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r ui-icon-shadow"></span><span class="ul-li-count ui-btn-corner-all ul-count-second"><?php echo count($mies) ?></span></div></li>

<?php  endforeach; ?>
```

So, probably need to use Count function(or length?), I don't know. If I am editing wrong place please advice if you have any experience in Concrete5 cms.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the corresponding page number in the `span` element in your code:

```
<span class="ul-li-count ui-btn-corner-all ul-count-second"><?php echo $mies; ?></span>
```

If you want to show the remaining sub-pages, then in the html code snippet above just replace `$mies` with `count($pages) - $mies` like:

```
<span class="ul-li-count ui-btn-corner-all ul-count-second"><?php echo count($pages) -$mies; ?></span>
```

You would first have to initialise `$mies` before you start the `for`loop so it should be something of the form:

```
<?php  
   $mies = 0;
   foreach ($pages as $page):
   //Rest of your code and increment $mies with every iteration
   $mies ++; //This ensures that you are counting the corresponding pages

?>
```

If you want to get the count of total number of sub-pages, you just have to echo out `$mies` outside the for block may be like:

```
<?php  
   endforeach; 
   echo $mies; //Shows you the total number of pages processed inside the for loop.
   //or Just find the length of pages array
   echo count($pages);
?>
```

As far as getting the length of array is concerned you could use `count` or `sizeof`. I stumbled upon a [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974385/php-array-count-or-sizeof) about using `count` or `sizeof` method for finding the length of an array.

This should get you started in the right direction.

Comment: It displays how many pages are in current page. I want it to show how many pages are below it.

Answer (score 0):

You need the parent ID;

```
$parentId = Page::getCollectionParentId();
```

Note that `Page::getCollectionParentId()` gets the current page's parent ID,so you may want to try;

```
$parentId = $page->getCollectionParentID();
```

Then create a new PageList to filter with and filter by the parentId;

```
Loader::model('page_list');
$pl = new PageList();
$pl->filter(false, '(p1.cParentID IN ' . $parentId . ')');

// Get the total
var_dump($pl->getTotal());
```

This is untested but the theory makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a bit simpler.

`$pl->getTotal()`

`$pl` is the `PageList` object that is set in the controller.

Also, these days you can just use the `h()` method instead of writing out `$th->entities()`

Edit: I should clarify that you don't need to do a `$pl = new PageList()` because `$pl` is already set to the `PageList` object in the controller and passed to the view.

Comment: This won't work - this gets the page count for the current page list. The OP wants the sub pages for each of the pages inside of `$pl`.