# What is the difference between count and sizeof?

Tags: php

I would like to count the number of values i have in some array.

what is the difference between `count` and `sizeof`?

```
$recips = array();
echo count($recips);
echo sizeof($recips);
```

Comment: None, `sizeof` is a alias of `count()`

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP array: count or sizeof?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974385/php-array-count-or-sizeof)

Comment: Read the manual : http://php.net/manual/en/function.sizeof.php

Comment: Alex's answer in the last @CodingCracker 's provided link is what you are looking for. It also helps to understand that sizeof is usually NOT what you actually mean, but in PHP it is just an alias of count.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These functions are aliases, like mentioned -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.sizeof.php

Answer (score 14):

'sizeof' is an alias of 'count' - at least according to the PHP manual!

In reality, the two functions behave differently, at least regarding the execution time - sizeof takes significantly longer to execute!

**The conclusion is: sizeof is NOT an alias for count**

Example:

```
<?php
$a = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; ++$i) {
    $a[] = 100;
}


function measureCall(\Closure $cb)
{
    $time = microtime(true);
    call_user_func($cb);
    return microtime(true) - $time;
}

for ($i = 0; $i < 3; ++$i) {
    echo measureCall(function () use ($a) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < 10000000; ++$i) {
                count($a);
            }
        }) . " seconds for count!\n";

    echo measureCall(function () use ($a) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < 10000000; ++$i) {
                sizeof($a);
            }
        }) . " seconds for sizeof!\n";
}
```

The outcome is:

```
0.9708309173584 seconds for count!
3.1121120452881 seconds for sizeof!
1.0040831565857 seconds for count!
3.2126860618591 seconds for sizeof!
1.0032908916473 seconds for count!
3.2952871322632 seconds for sizeof!
```

Update:
This test was executed on PHP 7.2.6

Comment: I think you shouldn't put both targets in same file... the first target can waste machine resources then give wrong results. I got equal result in my machine. `PHP 7.4.5 (cli) ( ZTS Visual C++ 2017 x64 )`