# How do I check if an array contains only one distinct element?

Tags: javascript

How do I check if my array contains only one distinct element? 
`

```
var arr = [1, 1, 1];
var arr2 = [1, 2, 3];
checkIfThereIsOnlyOneElement(arr); //should return true
checkIfThereIsOnlyOneElement(arr2) //should return false;`
```

Comment: one element means..same arguments?

Comment: Use `Array.length`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP array: count or sizeof?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974385/php-array-count-or-sizeof)

Comment: For checking if your array contains a value: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181575/determine-whether-an-array-contains-a-value . If you just want to know if the array 'is populated', as @Saravana said, use `Array.length`.

Comment: Loop over the array, starting with the second iteration of the loop (basically start the loop at 1 instead of 0) compare the element to the previous element.  If the comparison is ever false, return false.  After the loop, return true.

Comment: @Saravana how would that help me?

Comment: @PHPGeek that would be great if this was a php question...

Comment: @stephenpassero So you want to count unique values. I did not get that from reading your question. My bad.

Comment: @David thank you! That answered my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could implement it this way:

```js
var arr = [1, 1, 1];
var arr2 = [1, 2, 3];

console.log(checkIfThereIsOnlyOneElement(arr));
console.log(checkIfThereIsOnlyOneElement(arr2));

function checkIfThereIsOnlyOneElement(arr) {
    arr.sort();
    return arr[0] == arr[arr.length -1]
}
```

Comment: Very nice. Sort the array and then check to see if the first and last item are the same. The other answers complicate things.

Comment: @castis What if the array is one thousand elements long? I just guess the sorting function will be an overkill. The `Set` method seems to be much better, imo.

Comment: Well the OP had an example 3 elements long. No sense in over-engineering something just for that. If OP has a huge performance issue I assume they'll be back.

Answer (score 6):

Use [***Set***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) object:

```js
var arr = [1, 1, 1],
    arr2 = [1, 2, 3],
    checkForOne = function(arr){
        return (new Set(arr)).size === 1;
    }
    
console.log(checkForOne(arr));
console.log(checkForOne(arr2));
```

Comment: `Array.length` wouldn't be enough? What's the point to complicate the problem?

Comment: @Kinduser: How *would* `Array.length` be enough?

Comment: @Kinduser, the question seems to me about "one unique element". That's why the OP wanted `true` for `[1, 1, 1]`

Comment: @David Fine, if OP is looking for just unique elements, this is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

try this simple implementation

```
function checkIfThereIsOnlyOneElement(arr)
{
  var map = {};//create a map
  for( var counter = 0; counter < arr.length; counter++)
  {
    map[ arr[ counter ] ] = true;
    if ( Object.keys ( map ).length > 1 ) //check if this map has only one key
    {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: @Kinduser it is checking if there is only one unique element in the array or not.

Comment: @Kinduser didn't get you. `it's detonating opened door.` ??

Comment: @Kinduser i know, i meant to ask  - in what way i am doing so.

Answer (score 0):

simply check if all elements contain the same value, one way is to use "uniq" function of "lodash" module:

```
checkIfThereIsOnlyOneElement(arr){
     return _.uniq(arr).length == 1; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check unique values in array. Based on this term we can implement your function:

```js
var arr = [1, 1, 1];
var arr2 = [1, 2, 3];

function checkIfThereIsOnlyOneElement(arr) {
    return arr.filter(function (item, i, ar) {
            return ar.indexOf(item) === i;
        }).length === 1;
}

console.log(checkIfThereIsOnlyOneElement(arr));
console.log(checkIfThereIsOnlyOneElement(arr2));
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zhfpcthw/)

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of pretty easy implementations for this function. Let me give you two, one is a functional one-liner, the other is an iterative (probably better performing) snippet.

By the way, your naming is very bad, it should be called: `isArrayOfTheSameElements`

```
  // Iterative:
  function isArrayOfTheSameElements(arr){
    var firstElement = arr[0];
    for(var i=1; i < arr.length; i++){
      if (arr[i]!==firstElement) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  // Functional:
  function isArrayOfTheSameElements(arr){
    return Object.keys(arr.reduce(function(current, next){
      return current[next] = next && current;
    }, {})).length <= 1;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and check only agsindt the firsr element.

```js
function checkDistinct(array) {
    return array.every(function (a, _, aa) { return a === aa[0]; });
}

var arr = [1, 1, 1],
    arr2 = [1, 2, 3];

console.log(checkDistinct(arr));  // true
console.log(checkDistinct(arr2)); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always properly do like `.every()` as pointed out by [@Nina Scholz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43371025/4543207) but for a variety you may also do like;

```js
var all = a => a.length-1 ? a[0] === a[1] && all(a.slice(1)) : true;
console.log(all([1,1,1,1]));
console.log(all([1,1,1,2]));
```

It has the same benefit to cut the iteration once it meets a `false` value.