# Why is caching length in for loop faster using sizeof in PHP

Tags: php, performance, comparison

In this post a user calculated the performance of `sizeof` vs. `count`.

Turns out its faster (although less readable) to use `sizeof` to cache the length of the array instead of `count`.

It doesn't really make sense to me because sizeof is just an alias to count and, at least in my mind, it produces at least 1 additional machine call (since it resolves to count...).

Am I missing something critical here or is it actually slower but the calculation is wrong?

Is this behavior dependend on an opcode cache?

Here is the thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23410780/1268652

Comment: It just demonstrates how flaky microbenchmarks are and how it is complicated to write a reliable one.

Comment: I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3974399/1255289) to the same question is the one to be looking at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing microbenchmarks is hard. *Really* hard.

Getting reliable, repeatable, statistically significant, statistically sound results from a microbenchmark requires an advanced level of understanding of statistics, an advanced level of understanding of all the possible implementations and their possible optimizations (and ideally even not-yet-existing implementations and future optimizations), an advanced level of understanding of the code involved, and lots of experience writing microbenchmarks. People who write benchmarks are typically specialized professionals who do nothing but write benchmarks all day, every day for years. And even then, they get it wrong. IIRC, there was a famous case of a SPEC benchmark (pretty much *the* organization specializing in benchmarking) which was supposed to test the performance of database drivers but actually ended up testing memory allocator performance.

And even *if* you manage to write a reliable, repeatable, statistically significant, statistically sound microbenchmark, you will end up with perfectly reliable, perfectly repeatable, statistically significant, statistically sound results which are also perfectly useless, because microbenchmarks pretty much by *definition* don't reflect your actual real-world use case, loads, and environment.

All that to say: There cannot possibly be any performance difference. The only way a benchmark can possibly claim otherwise is if the benchmark is broken. Aliases are literally implemented as two names for the same code; it does not matter which name you use.

Answer (score 2):

> Am I missing something critical here or is it actually slower but the calculation is wrong?

You're missing nothing, the results simply are not reliable.

> Is this behavior dependend on an opcode cache?

It is not.

In terms of implementation

```
#define ZEND_FE(name, arg_info)                     ZEND_FENTRY(name, ZEND_FN(name), arg_info, 0)
#define ZEND_FALIAS(name, alias, arg_info)          ZEND_FENTRY(name, ZEND_FN(alias), arg_info, 0)
```

that's how "normal" and aliases functions are declared. So as you can see - it is identical.

Which means, the results should not be distinguishable from the outside of the Zend Engine.

Comment: Writing microbenchmarks is hard. *Really* hard. Getting reliable, repeatable, statistically significant results from a microbenchmark requires advanced level of understanding of statistics, advanced level of understanding of all the possible implementations and their possible optimizations (and ideally even not-yet-existing implementations and future optimizations), advanced level of understanding of the code involved, and *lots* of experience writing microbenchmarks. People who write benchmarks are typically specialized professionals who do nothing *but* write benchmarks all day, every day …

Comment: … for years. And even then, they get it wrong. IIRC, there was a famous case of a SPEC benchmark (pretty much *the* organization specializing in benchmarking) which was supposed to test the performance of database drivers but actually ended up testing memory allocator performance. And even *if* you manage to write a reliable, repeatable, statistically significant microbenchmark, you will end up with perfectly reliable, perfectly repeatable, statistically significant results which are also perfectly useless, because microbenchmarks pretty much by *definition* don't reflect your real-world use.

Comment: All that to say: +1. *There cannot possibly be* any performance difference. The only way a benchmark can possibly claim otherwise is if the benchmark is broken. (I'm assuming the code in other PHP implementations such as Quercus or P8 is similar.)

Comment: @JörgWMittag that's an amazing comment that deserves to be posted as a separate answer.